# How to use the Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection object when Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection is expected?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to list products on a category page filtered by an extension that hides products in a given category from customers except for those in the approved customer groups.

The filter requires the product collection to be passed along for processing. A Helper class is used to do this by overriding the `prepareProductCollection` function `in Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer`.

The collection is expected to be of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection` at this point but the collection being passed to the class extending `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer` is of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` which is causing the Helper class to fail. If you look at the stack trace below, all Magento classes being used before the function are expecting to return `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection`.

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog_Helper_Data::addGroupsFilterToProductCollection() must be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection, instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection given, called in /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Model/Catalog/Layer.php on line 37 and defined  in /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Helper/Data.php on line 475

#0 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Helper/Data.php(475): mageCoreErrorHandler(4096, 'Argument 1 pass...', '/home/namespace/...', 475, Array)
#1 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/GroupsCatalog/Model/Catalog/Layer.php(37): Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog_Helper_Data->addGroupsFilterToProductCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection))
#2 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(103): Netzarbeiter_GroupsCatalog_Model_Catalog_Layer->prepareProductCollection(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection))
#3 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(87): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getProductCollection()
#4 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#5 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#6 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#8 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(90): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#9 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/design/frontend/safes/default/template/local/catalog/category/view.phtml(87): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#10 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/namespace/...')
#11 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/safes/...')
#12 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#18 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/design/frontend/safes/default/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#19 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/namespace/...')
#20 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/safes/...')
#21 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/local/Aserty/Filter/controllers/CategoryController.php(34): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Aserty_Filter_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/namespace/public_html/b2b/index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Comment: _Little help_ Its recoverable!

Comment: Is this *your* module or a third party extension?

Comment: @RobbieAverill It's a third party extension. I was able to get it working by changing the method signature to use the Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection Object that is being given, but I want to understand under what circumstance would Magento be giving this object when it seems Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection is expected. 

If you'll notice, the overriding is starting at Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer but /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php seems to be passing the unexpected Object type.

Comment: @wickedskaman I can't see any of the code for this extension, so best to ask the author of it to explain it

Comment: @RobbieAverill that's the thing... I don't think the extension is causing the wrong Object type to be passed along. It seems Magento is doing that all its own and I would like to know if there's a situation when calling the Product List at the Block level (uses the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List Object) would be giving us an unexpected Object as it is here.

Am I calling the block wrong in the template? Is there a setting in the category that would not use the Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection Object as a result?

Comment: What I mean is that it could be the author's fault for type hinting a collection object that is too specific. The `age_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` type hint should be enough, the only exception would be if the class **requires** EAV collections specifically. Without seeing the code I can't really say any further. It sounds like you've done the right thing in making that change.

Answer (score 0):

The `Mysql4` classes are deprecated since Magento 1.5 or 1.6 and only exist for backwards compatiblity. If you look at their source code, you'll see that they extend the "new" resource models without any own code:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
{
}
```

Now this works fine until an extension type hints against the old class but Magento actually instantiates the new one.

Try to get a more recent version of the extension that is compatible with current Magento versions. If that's not possible, you can patch it yourself by replacing all `Mysql4` type hints.